# Unsure if passing by reference is working

Tags: c#, .net, micro-optimization

I've created a library for fun called [GamblersDice](https://github.com/mrtarantula/gamblers-dice). I'm trying to micro-optimize it but unsure if I'm doing it right. What I want is to use a reference to a global **Random** object when creating the die. The reason I believe it's not working is that testing **GamblersDie(random, int)** and **GamblersDie(ref random, int)** take nearly the same time over 10,000,000 iterations (test project is in the repo). If you don't want to scan through the repo, here are my constructors:

```
public class GamblersDie : Die
{
    private Random _rnd;

    public int[] Weight { get; private set; }

    public GamblersDie() : this(new Random()) { }

    public GamblersDie(int size) : this(new Random(), size) { }

    public GamblersDie(params int[] weights) : this(new Random(), weights) { }

    public GamblersDie(Random rnd) : this(ref rnd) { }

    public GamblersDie(Random rnd, int size) : this(ref rnd, size) { }

    public GamblersDie(Random rnd, params int[] weights) : this(ref rnd, weights) { }

    public GamblersDie(ref Random rnd) : this(ref rnd, 6) { }

    public GamblersDie(ref Random rnd, int size) {
        _rnd = rnd;
        Weight = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < Weight.Length; i++)
        {
            Weight[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    public GamblersDie(ref Random rnd, params int[] weights) : this(ref rnd, weights.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Weight.Length; i++)
        {
            Weight[i] = weights[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, this is just for fun. I **want** to micro-optimize it, just because it may be possible. Another question I have is about the constructor chaining. At first glance it may be confusing and I'm wonder if it's some kind of anti-pattern.

Comment: The resulting instructions are nearly the same, what do you expect? https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFAJiQGEkBvHJalAuAFiQFkAKAJwFMAzJAJTAB2AEwD2UJGwCUVGpWw0FKVAE52AOgByHAB7AWkyVnk0AvjOrnF+FI1b9hYidOPU5immlVtNOvQaMKZtgmQA===

Comment: Why do you want to pass it by ref? You're not assigning a new reference to the variable.

Comment: Why do you think you would get a difference in timing?

Comment: The only point of passing a reference to a class using `ref` is if you're going to *reassign* the parameter to a different reference and that should have an effect in the calling code. Since you never do `rnd = <anything>`, there's no point.

Comment: @stuartd my reasoning is that using a reference to the Random would decrease CPU time by reducing the number of copies of the Random object used when creating large numbers of dice.

Comment: The only confusing thing about your _"constructor chaining"_ is the fact you have _"GamblersDie(Random rnd, int size)"_ and _"GamblersDie(ref Random rnd, int size)"_ - looking at your coding they have the same effect as the _"rnd"_ parameter is not modified.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the info. I'm just trying to reduce the number of times the Random is copied when creating multiple dice. I see that ref is not the way to do so.

Comment: @MrTarantula: You could also remove the need to define _"GamblersDie(Random rnd)"_ & _"GamblersDie(Random rnd, int size)"_ separately by using a default parameter : _"GamblersDie(Random rnd, int size=6)"_. Similarly _"GamblersDie(int size=6)"_ removes the need for _"GamblersDie()"_

Comment: Passing references by ref unnecessarily should be a few nanoseconds *slower*, not *faster*.  The object is never copied; only a reference to the object is copied! Are you reasoning about C# as though it were C++?  Imagine that every variable of reference type has an invisible `&` in front of it; does that help?  What you are doing is adding *more* indirection, which is *not faster*.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, that's exactly what I was doing, thinking about C# as if it were C++. I actually did notice a slight slowdown over several million iterations when using ref, which is what led me to ask the question.

Comment: Quite fine. You might be interested in a new C# feature which allows you to pass large structs "by reference" but without making the alias a writable variable, unlike `ref` and `out`, which can pass structures by reference already. But you should never need to pass a *reference* by reference for performance reasons! It's already a reference-sized value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do variables/parameters hold? They hold *values*. What is the nature of the values they store? For Value types (`struct`) they store *the value itself*.

But for Reference types (`class`), they store a *reference*; they don't store the object itself, that's located elsewhere.

It is *these* that are copied-in in the default pass-by-value parameter passing in C#. And copying a *reference* is not the same as creating a copy of the object to which it refers. So, even without `ref`, you're dealing with a single *object* both inside and outside the method. Any changes *to the object* will, obviously, be visible externally.

You only need `ref` if a) you're going to *reassign* the parameter and that reassignment should be externally visible or b) you're mutating a Value type and that *mutation* should be externally visible.

---

And, in case the above isn't clear enough, I will explicitly state it here - [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) is a Reference type.

---

Bonus reading: [The Truth About Value Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/) by Eric Lippert, which you may not be ready for but does help dispel some common myths that you may pick up along the way.

Comment: In addition to the above answer - it should be noted that if you do not create a new instance of Random when creating each new GamblersDice object with _"GamblersDie(random, int)"_ or _"GamblersDie(ref random, int)"_ - then all of them will be reference the same instance (this may or may not be an issue for your application).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the concise explanation.

Comment: @PaulF I want to give users (however few they may be) the option to use a global instance or have the constructor create a new instance, which the constructors without Random parameters will do.